# Combine matrix elements into a hexadecimal number on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, hex

For example I have a matrix `command = ['01';'03';'0B';'00';'00';'02';'C6';'2F']`. I want to combine its elements in a hexadecimal number `01030C000002C62F`. I have tried a lot of different methods but haven't figured it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us! We are not here to solve your homework *instead of* you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `reshape(input_array.',1,[])`

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a `char` array:

```
A = ['01';'03';'0B';'00';'00';'02';'C6';'2F'];
```

Convert it to `cell`, then to `string`:

```
B = strjoin(cellstr(A))    
01030B000002C62F
```

Now convert from hexadecimal to decimal:

```
hex2dec(B)
ans =    
   7.2914e+16
```

Comment: Thanks you veery much for your  help, but i haven't managed to get it to work, this error is appearing:                                         Error using strjoin (line 53)
First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.
Error in convertion (line 2)
B = strjoin(cellstr(A))

Comment: Give me input vector A, which causes the crash. Code is double checked.

Comment: Its the same one i posted here, and the one you used in the example.Thank you very again

Comment: Check punctuation marks so. Solution works well, either mine, or Divakar's. What MATLAB version are you using?